# Importing and parsing JSON data from a URL in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to import JSON data from a URL (https://www.mapping.cityoflondon.gov.uk/arcgis/rest/services/COMPASS_Epping/MapServer/9?f=pjson)
into Power BI.

I click on Get Data -> URL -> put URL into "Basic" and get the following:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJYRl.png)

The data imported into Power BI is not usable in this form. How do we parse the data as we import from the URL?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the screenshot you shared, it seems after using the web connector, Power Query is reading the data as a CSV file.

[CSV.Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bUFL.png)

You can

1. Go to Source step in Power Query
2. In formula bar, replace CSV with JSON. Formula for Source step should look like

   = Json.Document(Web.Contents(URL))

Now Power BI will read it correctly as a JSON List. You can use the **Into Table** option to convert the list to table and make it more usable.

[JSON list to table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Abks.png)

Now I am not sure how do you want to see the data and you will be using it, but the above steps should make the data usable enough to perform any further transformations further on it and make use of it.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcISt.png)